# Is there a setting or app to make iPhone vibrate when a name or word is said?

Tags: accessibility, vibrate

My mother's new husband is great but very hard of hearing. This would be really useful for him and everybody else if we could get his iPhone to vibrate when people are trying to get his attention or when other important words or phrases are said.

I found the sound recognition settings that will notify you of things like coughs or door knocks, but strangely not for specific words.

Comment: How about just sending him a text? He doesn't have to text back if the person is in the same room. You can create contacts for people and set different vibrate patterns as well.

Comment: Lol. Yes I guess that's possible. But I'm thinking in terms of people hanging out in the living room, or having dinner together, so this might happen frequently. There's an app by Google called Live Transcription I think that will vibrate on name recognition, but it's only on android, not iphone.